# How to prevent only one UIViewController from rotating while other can rotate?

Tags: ios

I have Tab Bar Controller app with three UIViewController, all done in storyboard.
Device orientation is set to all, except Upside Down.

Rotation is supported, except for one UIViewController, for it should be only portrait.
I tried with:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

But when I rotate I get:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

So how to do it ?

Comment: This error message says you have a problem with your autolayout constraints. Normally there is an error / warning indicator in IB that points to what is wrong. Fix those problems and the error message will go away.

Comment: This appear only when I rotate that view, but that is whole point of my question. Because my constraints are valid only for portrait, not for landscape. So that Is why I wont to disable landscape.